# Laravel Auth::logout doesn't log the user out and session always has value

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, logout

I know there are lots of questions about this issue but none of them worked for me. I haven't used `php artisan make:auth` but `Auth::attempt()` is working however when I use `Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');` in my `routes.php` and

```
public function logout() {
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

in my `LoginController` it redirects to home page but again `auth()->user()` has value. How can I log user out completely in Laravel v5.8?

Comment: Try checking the error logs for any errors during session saving after logout

Comment: There is no error log in `storage/logs` but I found something surprised me. I closed the browser and open it again but the `auth()->check()` always returns true I even changed the browser I haven't used during that time but at the beginning of opening the new browser it returns true :| I'm shocked! how does it get value while it was the first time I was using that new browser?? Thanks

Comment: It uses the session. Usually the laravel session lasts for 1 hour or inactivity and the session is maintained using a cookie (so closing the browser will maintain the session assuming the browser keeps cookies). To simulate the start of a new session you can clear cookies or open in incognito

Comment: As I said I changed the browser but no result!

Comment: Sounds like a bug somewhere in your code.